# Setting Login page as default page in asp.net mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

i want this url "http://localhost:45678/" to bring me to my Login.cshtml that has a AccountController that contains

```
public ActionResult Login()
{
    return this.View();
}
```

This is how i do it in RoutesConfig.cs

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "AccountController", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

However, it is giving me a "Server Error in '/' Application." "The resource cannot be found.". what is the right way to do it?

Comment: `controller = "Account"` (not `"AccountController"`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your controller name is wrong. instead calling `AccountController`, you need to call `Account`.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Comment: ... i need more coffee. thanks man. i will accept your answer when i'm able to

Comment: @user1166085 no problem =)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public ActionResult Login()
{
  return View();
}
```

Make sure you have login page in the views section > Account

Answer (score 0):

Add authorization attribute to all the controllers where you need to be logged in.
then u create a redirect in your login logic.